# Add New Record Value, & Previous Record Value MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

I am busy creating a new table in my DB, and have some issues populating the correct values.

The table consists of a number of columns

```
| Date      | CustomerID | SKUCode | NewValueCaptured |PreviousDate| PreviousValueCaptured | 
|:----------|:-----------|:--------|:-----------------|:-----------|-----------------------|
| 2022-07-01| 123456     | 1028    | 10               |    NULL    |    NULL               |
| 2022-07-09| 123456     | 1028    | 15               | 2022-07-01 |     10                |
| 2022-07-12| 123456     | 1028    | 25               | 2022-07-01 |     15                |
| 2022-07-12| 123456     | 1029    | 8                | NULL       |     NULL              |
| 2022-07-01| 789123     | 1028    | 20               | NULL       |     NULL              |
| 2022-07-09| 789123     | 1028    | 10               | 2022-07-01 |     20                |
| 2022-07-01| 789123     | 1029    | 25               | NULL       |     NULL              |
| 2022-07-09| 789123     | 1029    | 13               | 2022-07-01 |     25                |
```

Using the UPDATE ON DUPLICATE KEY, is not an option here, as I need to keep each and every record, however, adding only the previous value to the new record.

Existing Query:

```
INSERT IGNORE INTO CS_data (Date, CustomerID , SKUCode, NewValueCaptured, PreviousDate, PreviousValueCaptured)    
   SELECT * FROM (SELECT DISTINCT
                     DWH.Date             'SRCDate'
                 ,   DWH.CustomerID  
                 ,   CASE
                     WHEN DWH.SKUCode IS NOT NULL THEN DWH.SKUCode
                     ELSE DWH.SKUCode
                     END                  'SKUCode'
                 ,   DWH.ValueCaptured    'SRCValueCaptured'
                 ) SRC
                 ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE
                    PreviousDate = Date
                 ,  PreviousValueCaptured = NewValueCaptured
                 ,  Date = SRCDate
                 ,  NewValueCaptured= SRCValueCaptured;
```

How do I achieve the above table results?  Rather than updating the existing record.

Thanks

Comment: I wouldn't capture previous position at all since it's easy enough to generate in a query.

Comment: @P.Salmon, under normal circumstances, I would agree, however in this example it is a business requirement to have the old result show side-by-side with the new result in the table in the table.

Comment: What is MySQl version?

Comment: @Akina MySQL Server 8.0, data is populated using PHP Version 8.1.2.

Comment: o_O On this version - simply use LAG(). PS. What does this means: `WHEN DWH.SKUCode IS NOT NULL THEN DWH.SKUCode ELSE DWH.SKUCode END`? The same value anycase - what is the reason?

Comment: @Akina I have never come across the LAG() function.  How does this work? 
The case statement you referring I just wanted to completely exclude blank values.  I do realise that the ELSE part is irrelevant in the example.

Comment: *I just wanted to completely exclude blank values* - ? You want to remove the rows with NULLs? Replace NULLs with some definite value (zero)? Replace NULLs with currect value?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/246572/discussion-between-leon-claassen-and-akina).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that you need in something like (demo only)

```sql
INSERT INTO destination_table (
    Date, 
    CustomerID, 
    SKUCode, 
    NewValueCaptured, 
    PreviousDate, 
    PreviousValueCaptured
)
SELECT Date, 
       CustomerID, 
       SKUCode, 
       ValueCaptured,
-- get Date value from previous row, if not exists use the value from current row
       COALESCE(LAG(Date) OVER (PARTITION BY CustomerID, SKUCode ORDER BY Date),
                Date),
-- and the same for ValueCaptured
       COALESCE(LAG(ValueCaptured) OVER (PARTITION BY CustomerID, SKUCode ORDER BY Date),
                ValueCaptured)
FROM source_table;
```

Documentation: [Window functions](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/window-functions.html).

Comment: This looks exactly like what I am looking for.  Thank you @Akina!!! My assumption is to then be able to append rows I will be adding a Unique Key to the Date and SKUCode fields, followed by running the query for a period of 90 days, to cover the time frame in which I want previous values to be recorded?